# PHP: Redirect main domain to https://www, subdomain to https:// (without www)

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, https, subdomain

I want to modify a `php`-file to fulfill the following needs:

**Main domain:**

- Redirect `http` to `https`
- Redirect `non-www` to `www`
- (for main domain, `www` is desired and should appear)

**Subdomains:**

- Redirect `http` to `https`
- Redirect `www` to `non-www`
- (for subdomains, `www` is not desired and should not appear)

---

**Comment:** The subdomain has a completely different content than the main domain (could be *private.website.com* or *cloud.website.com* for example). It is **not** just a different language. Because of this, it seems not useful to create a internal forwarding via browser or CMS. It should be executed via `.hataccess` in best case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using php then you need to write some conditions And you didn't give any example of sub domain IF you are going to use sub domain like de.example.com , uk.example.com then you need to redirect with the help of browser language Or you can also do it with the help of visitors locations

just like

```
<?php    
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

if($lang=="de")
{

header('Location: https://de.example.com/');

}    
?>
```

IN that case you need to do the followings.

1) http to https

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
```

2) non-www to www

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

3) www to non-www

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```