# .htaccess: Redirect main domain to https://www, subdomain to https:// (without www)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, dns, subdomain

I know there is an endless number of provided `.htaccess`-solutions around here, but none of them redirects to `https` with `www` only for main domain, but to `https` without `www` only for subdomains. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47873721/5017033) question with a solution via `php`, now I want to modify my `.htaccess`-file to fulfill the following needs.

**Main domain:**

- Redirect `http` to `https`
- Redirect `non-www` to `www`
- (for main domain: `www` **is** desired and should appear)

**Subdomains:**

- Redirect `http` to `https`
- Redirect `www` to `non-www`
- (for subdomains: `www` **is not** desired and should **not** appear)

---

**My current approach looks like that:**

```
RewriteEngine on

# Ensure https for all domains (main- and subdomains):
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirect non-www to www only for main domain, but not for subdomains:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirect www to non-www only for subdomains:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://subdomain.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

---

- There is some error with the subdomain I think?
- I don't understand the part `RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}` in the very first command: Doesn't this command send the visitor to the main domain when he enters the subdomain without `https`? Or does `{HTTP_HOST}` already include possible subdomains?

---

**Comment:** The subdomain has a completely different content than the main domain (could be *private.website.com* or *cloud.website.com* for example). It is not just a different language. Because of this, it seems not to be useful to create a internal forwarding via browser-origin or CMS. It should be performed via `.htaccess`-entry only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is duplicated for subdomain part, you should modify to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://subdomain.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

For these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Line 1: if the https is off

Line 2: for any patterns, redirect the user to `https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}` permanently. The `%{HTTP_HOST}` is obtained from the [HTTP request header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23) and when user made a request `domain.com`, the `%{HTTP_HOST}` is `domain.com`, whereas the this request `subdomain.domain.com` is made, the `%{HTTP_HOST}` is then `subdomain.domain.com`